# count the total number of files present in directory using c++

Tags: c++, filesystems, directory

I am trying to get number of files in a directory through c++ for unix OS
I have this code

```
int i;
i = (int)system("ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l");
cout << "Number of files " << i << endl;
```

But I am getting output as

```
21
Number of files 0
```

How can I get `21` in `i`

Comment: what is result when you run that command on bash ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're wanting can be achieved pretty easily by using the glob(2) function:

```
#include <glob.h>
int glob(const char *pattern, int flags,
                int (*errfunc) (const char *epath, int eerrno),
                glob_t *pglob);
```

Simple example (w/o error handling):

```
glob_t gl;
size_t num = 0;
if(glob("/root/opencv/*.png", GLOB_NOSORT, NULL, &gl) == 0)
  num = gl.gl_pathc;
globfree(&gl);
cout << "Number of files: " << num << endl;
```

Comment: Cool answer. Didn't know `glob` existed.

Answer (score 6):

Although you specify an OS a portable solution might be desirable.

Boost::Filesystems [directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator) and [std::count_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/count_if/) is what your are looking for. The predicate for `count_if` could either use `std::regex` or whatever is enough for you.

Here is a minimal example exhibiting the desired behaviour (no recursion included):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
  int i =  std::count_if(fs::directory_iterator("/your/path/here/"),
                         fs::directory_iterator(), 
                         [](const fs::directory_entry& e) { 
                          return e.path().extension() == ".png";  });
  //also consider recursive_directory_iterator
  std::cout << i << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `system` call returns the exit status of the shell in UNIX. So, it makes sense for it to return `0`.

You will need to parse the output of `system` function if you want to get the file count. Otherwise, use a system call to count how many PNG files on directory you want.

Take a look at `opendir` and `readdir` functions. It will be better to use those functions instead of parsing `system` output.

Comment: +1 Sorry I am new as I am working on opencv so not very familiar with c++ but parsing what you are saying isn't in this line of code `i = (int)system("ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l");` where I am using (int) to parse.

Comment: @Wazzzy: you need to parse system function call output. Or use something like `execv`. I would recommend using `opendir` and `readdir` for what you are trying to accomplish though...

Comment: @Wazzzy: take a look at the answer with `glob`. It seems to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

That is to be expected. The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) of system says:

> Return Value
>
> The value returned is -1 on error (e.g. fork(2) failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.

You really don't want to call system and ls here, the standard way to do this would be either through [opendir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) and [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) for an entire or through [glob](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) if you just look for filename patterns.

If you insist on spawning three processes to count the number of files in a directory, you should look into [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to read the output from your command.

Comment: Should I use `i = (int)popen("ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l","r");`

Comment: Sadly, things aren't that easy (this is C, after all...). Popen will return you a FILE* object, from which you can fread into a buffer which you can then atoi or fscanf from...

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you get the command's return value, and not the output.

If you want to use the system command `ls` and not `opendir` and `readdir` as others suggested, you should use **`popen`** instead of `system`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    FILE *in;
    char buff[512];

    /* popen creates a pipe so we can read the output
       of the program we are invoking */
    if (!(in = popen("ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l", "r"))) 
    {  
        /* if popen failed */
        return 1;
    }

    /* read the output of ls, one line at a time */
    while (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in) != NULL ) 
    {
        printf("Number of files: %s", buff);
    }

    /* close the pipe */
    pclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should I use `i = (int)popen("ls -l /root/opencv/*.png|wc -l","r");`